# Linear programming dual simplex method problem

Tags: simplex-method

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlqVa.jpg)

I've this question and I changed the sign for the max Z and then found the dual of primal. But here the problem is that now I have -ve values in ratio. I am thinking of changing the min to max by introducing negative sign but I wanted to solve it by the conventional procedure of dual method. Any help in this regard is appreciated..